# Resize NTFS partition from Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I have an external hard drive that I used for backups of my Windows machine. I left that machine behind but took the drive when I moved to a new city. So far, I've only bought and used a Macbook in the new city. I want to use this external drive for Time Machine, but when I first got the drive, I decided to format it in a single, large, 2TB NTFS partition. Is there a tool that runs in OS X that will let me resize an NTFS partition without losing the data?

Comment: Do you have an objection to using the [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php)?

Comment: I would not, if this computer had an optical drive. I'm on a 2013 Macbook Pro Retina running OS X 10.9.3. Ideally, I'd like to avoid buying a drive just for this purpose, but I can ask at work to see if I can borrow one.

Comment: Uhhh...Perhaps [this](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php) would work then? It is the way I use it.

Comment: Oh cool, didn't see that. Maybe I can use [Mac Linux USB](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/) to create it. I'll give it a shot when I get more time. Thanks!

Comment: Seems there are a [few possibilities](http://guides.macrumors.com/Extend_or_Resize_Boot_Camp_Partition). iPartition worked great for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GParted would be able to do that.
You could boot from a [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) or a [GParted LiveUSB](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php).

Comment: Tried today. Failed while booting with the error "no suitable video mode found, trying blind boot" or similar. I assume it's because it doesn't have a suitable driver for a Macbook Retina display. Is it not possible to run gparted directly from my Mac?